# Storing object references in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite, angularjs, database-design

I'm currently building a pretty complex AngularJS application that stores data in a sqlite database. My application data contains references to objects that are shared throughout the app. Angular is able to render this data, compare it, and everything has been fine so far.

What do I mean by all of this? Check out this example for the "boilerplate" of the objects in my application.

```
var Person = {
    name:'some person',
    owns:[]
}

var Cat = {
    name:'some cat'
}

var project = {
    name:'some project',
    people:[],
    cats:[]
}
```

My application will allow users to create and manipulate these objects, and create relationships between them. Instances of `Person` may be created, and each `Person` object may store references to instances of `Cat`.

As you may have already guessed, my `project` will eventually look like this after the user is done manipulating it.

```
var project = {
    name:'some project',
    people:[person, person, person],
    cats:[cat, cat cat, cat, cat, cat]
}

console.log(project.people[0].owns)
//logs something like "cat, cat, cat". These are references.
```

My application then has views set up to view each `person` and will list out the `owns` property, which contains the instances of `Cat`.

All is fine in dandy until I realized that there may be complications storing this as JSON in a database. `JSON.Stringify()` and `angular.toJSON()` do not treat references as references, instead they read them as individual objects.

I am hoping to gain some insights on the best way to preserve these relationships/references.

Here are the two options that I believe I have.

**Option 1:** 
Scrap the idea of storing this in JSON, and use a relational database to store everything. This isn't ideal because it starts to eat away at the flexible nature of object rendering in AngularJS. Additionally, this data will be stored in multiple places (online & locally) which may present differences in the database scheme which would be a debugging nightmare.

**Option 2:**
Store a unique identifier with each instance of `Person` and `Cat`. I can then use this identifier when rendering and creating the associations. This will work if I create custom filters in Angular, but globally removing references when objects are deleted could be a nightmare.

Comment: I don't really know how these JSON DBs store their data, but don't you already have an infinite regress problem when you try to serialize "Fred owns Dino" alongside "Dino is owned by Fred"?  So it's not even a matter of retrieval, but that there seems to be no clear way of storing these unless the DB is already creating references for you...  Or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: You are correct Scott, I edited my question to reflect your concern. In my app (and in the example above) it's a one-way relationship. "owned_by" was not needed, and I missed that at first.

Comment: With this, I believe some of the JSON storage engines such as Mongo and Couch would store enough meta-data to reconstruct these relationships on retrieval of your `project` object.  But I don't know about sqllite.  What they wouldn't retrieve is any construtor functions that you might use to create these objects.  If you're using just plain JS objects, this won't hurt at all.

Comment: on Option2: can you please explain bit more reg. "This will work if I create custom filters in Angular, but globally removing references when objects are deleted could be a nightmare."

Comment: I've been considering similar issues myself. I was leaning to each instance with some locally-(or globally?) unique ID as well, but for other reasons. Essentially to encourage separation of concerns for client side storage of objects, and OO-type methods to calculate any derived data. For example, could have Cat and Person services, that exposes methods like Cat.getOwnedBy(personId) and PersonService.getAge(personId). Each service would as much as possible only deal with data of its "class".

Comment: Mahes, to expand upon my comment I would offer this scenario. An object is referenced by many other objects, and it works well because when that object changes it's updated everywhere. My solution would be that I would have to store a unique hash for that object, and perform a look-up every time I need it. This isn't a bad solution really, but if the object ceases to exist, each time the look-up is performed there would need to be a cleanup. After considering this, references really do have the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditional table based relation databases have solved this problem.  Each record/document that could be referenced in multiple contexts is stored in it own table/collection with an `id`.  That `id` is referenced by other objects in their own collections.

`JSON` itself will only hold raw data, so as you note, object references that change is not something `JSON` can handle.

So the question becomes, is the data a relationship between first order objects? Or is it nested/embedded in another object?

In your example, a project has many people, a project has many cats, and people has many projects.  So because people and projects both need to be referenced by multiple other objects, each resource should be it's own resource, reference by a foreign key.

```
// projects.json
[
  {
    id: 4
    name: 'homework',
    person_ids: [1,2,3],
  }
]

// people.json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    project_ids: [4,5,6],
  }
]
```

A good case for embedding might be comments on a project.  In this case, you always access the comments through the projects.  And because a comment can only ever belong to a single project, embedding it makes more sense.

```
// projects.json
[
  {
    id: 4
    name: 'homework',
    person_ids: [1,2,3],
    comments: [
      {
         person_id: 1,
         message: 'My dog ate it'
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

---

I'd recommend reading up on how [Mongoid handles relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many).  It's a ruby wrapper for MongoDB, but the docs explain how it structures the collections to enable relationships.  You might find it quite helpful to get your head around how this would work.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is a great response and provides the insights I was looking for. I'm going to leave this topic open a little longer because I feel that it's a good, thought provoking conversation that may attract more answers.